# Gráfico iniciando no valor errado (eixo x)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Tenho uma base que inicia em 2010-12-31, mas quando faço o ggplot2, o gráfico de colunas inicia em 2011.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Eis o código utilizado:**

```
# Pacotes

library(tidyverse)
library(GetDFPData2)
library(scales)
options(scipen = 999)
```

**#Extração dos balanços**

```
df_info <- get_info_companies(tempdir())
search_company('PETRÓLEO BRASILEIRO  S.A.  - PETROBRAS')
dfp <- get_dfp_data(companies_cvm_codes = 9512,
                    use_memoise = F,
                    clean_data = T,
                    type_docs = 'DRE',
                    type_format = 'con',
                    first_year = 2010,
                    last_year = 2022)
```

**#Base DRE**

```
dre_annual <- dfp$`DF Consolidado - Demonstração do Resultado` %>% 
  filter(CD_CONTA == '3.11')
```

**Gráfico**

```
dre_annual %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DT_REFER, y = VL_CONTA/1000000)) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks('1 year'),
               labels = date_format('%Y')) +
  theme_light() +
  labs (
    x = 'Ano', 
    y = 'Valor (em R$ bilhões)',
    title = 'Lucro/prejuízo da Petrobras')
```

Comment: Seu gráfico começa de 2010, porém sem valor (zero). Qual o resultado de `VL_CONTA/1000000` para 31/12/2010? Talvez esteja tão perto de zero que não aparece.

Answer (score 5):

O problema aqui está na coluna `DT_REFER`. Como ela considera o último dia do ano, a coluna com as datas acaba ficando deslocada:

```r
dre_annual %>%
  select(DT_REFER, VL_CONTA) %>%
  mutate(VL_CONTA = VL_CONTA/1000000)
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   DT_REFER   VL_CONTA
   <date>        <dbl>
 1 2010-12-31   35.9  
 2 2011-12-31   33.1  
 3 2012-12-31   21.0  
 4 2013-12-31   23.0  
 5 2014-12-31  -21.9  
 6 2015-12-31  -35.2  
 7 2016-12-31  -13.0  
 8 2017-12-31    0.377
 9 2018-12-31   26.7  
10 2019-12-31   41.0  
11 2020-12-31    6.25 
12 2021-12-31  107.
```

Uma maneira de solucionar isso é utilizar apenas o ano da coluna `DT_REFER`. O pacote `lubridate` possui a função `year`, capaz de lidar com isso:

```r
dre_annual %>%
  select(DT_REFER, VL_CONTA) %>%
  mutate(DT_REFER = year(DT_REFER), 
         VL_CONTA = VL_CONTA/1000000)
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   DT_REFER VL_CONTA
      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     2010   35.9  
 2     2011   33.1  
 3     2012   21.0  
 4     2013   23.0  
 5     2014  -21.9  
 6     2015  -35.2  
 7     2016  -13.0  
 8     2017    0.377
 9     2018   26.7  
10     2019   41.0  
11     2020    6.25 
12     2021  107.
```

O problema é que isso faz com que a coluna `DT_REFER`, que era do tipo *date* (ou seja, uma data), vire *dbl* (ponto flutuante de dupla precisão). Assim, as opções do `ggplot2` usadas para criar o espaçamento do eixo x do gráfico não poderão mais ser utilizadas, pois elas são baseadas em datas. Por isso, recomendo criar uma nova coluna `DT_REFER`, mas referenciada em 1 de janeiro:

```r
dre_annual %>%
    select(DT_REFER, VL_CONTA) %>%
    mutate(DT_REFER = ymd(paste0(year(DT_REFER), "-01-01")), 
           VL_CONTA = VL_CONTA/1000000)
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   DT_REFER   VL_CONTA
   <date>        <dbl>
 1 2010-01-01   35.9  
 2 2011-01-01   33.1  
 3 2012-01-01   21.0  
 4 2013-01-01   23.0  
 5 2014-01-01  -21.9  
 6 2015-01-01  -35.2  
 7 2016-01-01  -13.0  
 8 2017-01-01    0.377
 9 2018-01-01   26.7  
10 2019-01-01   41.0  
11 2020-01-01    6.25 
12 2021-01-01  107.
```

`paste0` é uma função que junta duas strings, sem colocar espaço ou outro marcador entre elas. Assim, eu juntei o ano (resultado da aplicação da função `year`) com a string `-01-01`. Em seguida, transformei em uma data, usando a função `ymd` (year, month, day - ano, mês, dia), também do pacote `lubridate`.

Juntando tudo, temos o seguinte resultado:

```r
dre_annual %>%
  select(DT_REFER, VL_CONTA) %>%
  mutate(DT_REFER = ymd(paste0(year(DT_REFER), "-01-01")), 
         VL_CONTA = VL_CONTA/1000000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DT_REFER, y = VL_CONTA)) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks('1 year'),
               labels = date_format('%Y')) +
  theme_light() +
  labs (
    x = 'Ano', 
    y = 'Valor (em R$ bilhões)',
    title = 'Lucro/prejuízo da Petrobras')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]